# Find $\sum{(-1)^22n }$ from $n=0$ to $n=28$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

Find $\sum{(-1)^22n }$ from $n=0$ to $n=28$

I can't find a formula for alternation series

Comment: Do you mean $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{28}(-1)^n2n$?

Comment: Since $(-1)^2=1$ the series does not alternate as written.

Comment: Are you sure you copied that down correctly? Because that is *not* an alternating series.  $\sum_{n=0}^{28} (-1)^{\color{red}{2}} 2n = \sum_{n=0}^{28} 2n = 28(28+1)=812$

Comment: PS: the formula for one alternating series is: $\sum_{n=0}^N (-1)^n n = \tfrac 1 4 (2N (-1)^N+(-1)^N-1)$

Answer (score 1):

If it's an alternating series I assume you mean
$$S=\sum_{n=0}^{28}(-1)^n(2n)\ .$$
If this is the case, **hint**: group the terms in pairs as far as possible,
$$S=(0-2)+(4-6)+(8-10)+\cdots+(52-54)+56\ .$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

It is

$$\sum{(-1)^22n }=\sum{2n }=2\sum{n }=2\times \frac{(1+28)\times 28}{2} =28\times 29$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Assuming your mean $\sum_{n=0}^{28}(-1)^n2n$, note that you can combine each even term with the odd one after it and get $-2$. How many pairs are there?  Then you didn't have anything to combine $n=28$ with, so add that in by hand.